# ASP - Why does this img not display

Tags: asp.net, html

The following code will not display the image, it does show that an image is present but the image does not display. Any ideas?

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main_MP.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Phone.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Phone1" Title="Talk & Txt" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<img src="Talk & Txt Page.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />

    <br />
<asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#C00000"></asp:Label></div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: XHTML can't have raw `&` characters in it.

`&` and spaces are not safe characters for URIs.

Comment: I suspect your alt text leaves something to be desired, http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html is recommended reading.

Comment: Some basic debugging is expected. What does Firebug / Chrome debug tools / etc report as the URL being requested? What HTTP response code does the server return?

Answer (score 2):

The unescaped ampersands may be causing your issue.

Comment: +1.  Futher, renaming the image would be a good idea. Aviod using these characters: http://dslrphotoforum.com/index.php?topic=211.0

Answer (score 1):

Rename the image file to `TalkAndTxtPage.jpg` - All files linked via URL, including images, are best named without using reserved or unsafe characters (both space (" ") and ampersand ("&") fit into this category). Reference - http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Then do this (you also had a bad `<div>` tag):

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main_MP.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Phone.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Phone1" Title="Talk & Txt" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<img src="TalkAndTxtPage.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />

    <br />
<asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#C00000"></asp:Label>
    <div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Good answer, so +1.  It could be better if you included ***why*** Ross should rename the image.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces in the image URL (ie, the 'src') attribute with %20.

You can't have spaces in a URL, but %20 should work.

Comment: I doubt that is the issue. Browsers are remarkably good at recovering from that particular error.

Answer (score 0):

Does that image is in the same directory as the page, otherwise you need to give the full relative path

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from the image name.

```
<img src="Talk-Txt-Page.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />
```

Also, where is the image located in relation to the page? You might need to point to the directory.

```
<img src="/images/Talk-Txt-Page.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The spaces in the image name should not cause an issue - I just tested that

Answer (score 0):

this alone with an image named Talk & Txt Page.jpg works on my side.

I see a couple of ending div tags in your code that do not have a beginning div